# Can I use AWS Certificate Manager certificates for API Gateway with Custom Domain Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-certificate-manager

Can I use a certificate from AWS Certificate Manager to use it with API Gateway and my Custom Domain Name?

How do I get the certificate body, private key and chain out of the certificate from the AWS Certificate Manager?

Comment: You can't do this at this time without creating another CloudFront distribution in addition to the one created behind the scenes by API Gateway.

Comment: @MarkB does that mean there is a workaround using "another CloudFront distribution" as you say?

Comment: Cloudfront workaround appears possible in the docs, but the option is grayed out for me so far ++ See "To use alternate domain names with HTTPS" ++ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html#CNAMEsAndHTTPS

Comment: A second cloudfront distro in front of API gateway will work as @MarkB suggested. You have to whitelist headers and prevent the `Host` header from forwarding to API gateway as it uses SNI.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

<strike>As you saw in the forum post, it's not possible now. ACM integration is something we want to do and it's on our backlog, but I don't have an ETA for you at the moment.</strike>

[ACM is now integrated with API Gateway!](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/03/amazon-api-gateway-integrates-with-aws-certificate-manager-acm/)

Comment: Thank you. Please keep us updated here too once it will be available.

Comment: Related, is there any way to *update* an expired cert? You can't edit it in the web UI and the cloudfront distribution isn't visible for updating.

Comment: Yep, we're working on getting support out to update certificates in-place. Right now you can either delete the domain and recreate it (takes 40 minutes), or if you require zero down time we can do an in-place cert rotation if you open a support ticket and tell them that's what you need.

Comment: @JackKohn-AWS this just bit our team really hard and it seems that we messed up by using AWS to register our domain/cert ... seems like this is a HUGE fail on AWS's end by making their own services incompatible with each other... Is there any update on this?

Comment: I'd like to add my voice to this as a highly desirable feature/improvement. Is there an official place to add a vote etc?

Comment: Yet another AWS half-baked release. If AWS were a restaurant all the food would be served raw.

Comment: Absolutely stunned this isn't available for API gateway. How are we supposed to use Route 53 domains in this case?

Comment: I was honestly so confused by this and am grateful that this question was posted.  This seems like a pretty large oversight and will indeed be aa problem for us too. Please Amazon, make this one happen soon!